# Here Map iOS Navigate SDK map not loading

Tags: ios, swift, here-api

I have dowloaded Here Maps Navigate Edition iOS SDK and integrated successful. But since yesterday the map is not loading. I try the demo (HelloMap) with my own credentials but nothing happened, not loading at all. I have added App Transport Security Settings and exception for the here.com domain, and try with VPN and without VPN with no results. I'm using version:

heresdk-navigate-ios-4.12.11.0.10055

and Xcode 13.3 with iOS 14.0 (simulator) and iPhone Device, but the Xcode console is showing this log's:

```
2022-11-26 16:08:20.561031-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] HERESDK Version 4.12.11
2022-11-26 16:08:20.726024-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] LockingProcess - Neither cache nor persistent map storage is locked
16:08:20.727 [INFO] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_0'
16:08:20.727 [INFO] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_1'
16:08:20.728 [INFO] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_1'
16:08:20.728 [INFO] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_0'
2022-11-26 16:08:20.752943-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] Storage.LevelDB - Cleared other DB in folder: "/Users/Wo_0NDeR/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/850AA0EB-4DCD-4F76-B066-307514C13CC3/data/Containers/Data/Application/64F0F972-D450-40C2-9F5B-0C7A121FD322/Library/Caches/v1/sBc3L41ElBGY3rJkHFA/analyticsData/events.sqlite
2022-11-26 16:08:20.762753-0500 HelloMap[22059:397456] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C2.1.1:3] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-11-26 16:08:20.908414-0500 HelloMap[22059:397456] Connection 2: received failure notification
2022-11-26 16:08:20.909445-0500 HelloMap[22059:397456] Connection 2: failed to connect 1:61, reason -1
2022-11-26 16:08:20.910176-0500 HelloMap[22059:397456] Connection 2: encountered error(1:61)
2022-11-26 16:08:20.913989-0500 HelloMap[22059:397450] Task <C5CE21CD-112F-45A3-8C08-A6B23E12237F>.<2> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2022-11-26 16:08:20.961543-0500 HelloMap[22059:397450] Task <C5CE21CD-112F-45A3-8C08-A6B23E12237F>.<2> finished with error [-1004] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001a2c3f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, expensive, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <C5CE21CD-112F-45A3-8C08-A6B23E12237F>.<2>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <C5CE21CD-112F-45A3-8C08-A6B23E12237F>.<2>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2022-11-26 16:08:20.963253-0500 HelloMap[22059:397463] [log] [ERROR] Authentication - Failed to SignInClient: ApiError(ErrorCode: 11, Message: Could not connect to the server., HTTPStatusCode: -1)
2022-11-26 16:08:20.964169-0500 HelloMap[22059:397463] [log] [ERROR] Authorization - Authorization fail. Failed to get token: 7
2022-11-26 16:08:20.979368-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] SDKNativeEngineImpl - Creation
2022-11-26 16:08:20.993233-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] Metal API Validation Enabled
2022-11-26 16:08:21.069186-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Initializing SDK renderer with a threaded render loop
2022-11-26 16:08:21.069510-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Starting render loop thread (state=<paused>)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.070856-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] magma-graphics-metal - Initialized Metal graphics implementation.
2022-11-26 16:08:21.075870-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] CL_magma - Failed to load texture file 'spot_light_glow.pvrtc1rgba4.tex'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.076122-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] CL_magma - Failed to load texture file 'light_flare.pvrtc1rgba4.tex'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.076785-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] geoviz - Created GraphicsPackage 'Metal' for GPU='VendorId=Apple ModelFamily= ModelCode=0'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.076919-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] scheduler - Starting threaded task scheduler with:
2022-11-26 16:08:21.077061-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] scheduler -    name(fileLoad) queue#(1) executor#(1)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.077370-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] scheduler -    name(default) queue#(1) executor#(3)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.077547-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] scheduler -    name(download) queue#(1) executor#(8)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.077774-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] scheduler -    name(lowPriority) queue#(1) executor#(1)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.077935-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] scheduler -    name(update) queue#(1) executor#(0)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.078109-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] scheduler -    name(draw) queue#(1) executor#(1)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.081925-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Render loop thread created
2022-11-26 16:08:21.082350-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] maploader:DataStoreProviderImpl - Network is reachable
2022-11-26 16:08:21.082910-0500 HelloMap[22059:397491] [log] [INFO ] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_0'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.083082-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DefaultSchemaDecoder - Default decoder created, schema='v1.39.0'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.083243-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreServer - Server created, mutable_cache=true, protected_cache=true, political_view_iso_id=none, this=0x7f965e80b400
2022-11-26 16:08:21.083464-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreServer - No schema decoder set, default decoder used
2022-11-26 16:08:21.084055-0500 HelloMap[22059:397493] [log] [INFO ] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_2'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.084823-0500 HelloMap[22059:397492] [log] [INFO ] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_1'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.085267-0500 HelloMap[22059:397495] [log] [INFO ] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_4'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.085489-0500 HelloMap[22059:397497] [log] [INFO ] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_6'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.086569-0500 HelloMap[22059:397494] [log] [INFO ] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_3'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.089008-0500 HelloMap[22059:397498] [log] [INFO ] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_7'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.089769-0500 HelloMap[22059:397496] [log] [INFO ] ThreadPoolTaskScheduler - Starting thread 'OLPSDKPOOL_5'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.093237-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C3.1.1:3] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-11-26 16:08:21.096573-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Connection 3: received failure notification
2022-11-26 16:08:21.096786-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Connection 3: failed to connect 1:61, reason -1
2022-11-26 16:08:21.097046-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Connection 3: encountered error(1:61)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.100679-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Task <F3551C49-F722-4DA4-AA52-3CA5795D342D>.<3> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2022-11-26 16:08:21.101453-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Task <F3551C49-F722-4DA4-AA52-3CA5795D342D>.<3> finished with error [-1004] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001ad21c0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, expensive, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <F3551C49-F722-4DA4-AA52-3CA5795D342D>.<3>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <F3551C49-F722-4DA4-AA52-3CA5795D342D>.<3>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2022-11-26 16:08:21.102481-0500 HelloMap[22059:397464] [log] [ERROR] Authentication - Failed to SignInClient: ApiError(ErrorCode: 11, Message: Could not connect to the server., HTTPStatusCode: -1)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.103135-0500 HelloMap[22059:397464] [log] [ERROR] Authorization - Authorization fail. Failed to get token: 7
2022-11-26 16:08:21.103363-0500 HelloMap[22059:397456] [log] [ERROR] Authentication - Internet connectivity is not available
2022-11-26 16:08:21.103512-0500 HelloMap[22059:397456] [log] [ERROR] analytics - Failed to get the authentication client id: Internet connectivity is not available, error code: 7
2022-11-26 16:08:21.103659-0500 HelloMap[22059:397456] [log] [ERROR] analytics - Invalid access key
2022-11-26 16:08:21.104248-0500 HelloMap[22059:397456] [log] [ERROR] maploader:DataStoreProviderImpl - Failed to receive Japan decision, error: Authentication failed
2022-11-26 16:08:21.104409-0500 HelloMap[22059:397456] [log] [INFO ] maploader:DataStoreProviderImpl - Decision API (Catalog configuration) done.
2022-11-26 16:08:21.146348-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DefaultCache - Initializing mutable LRU cache
2022-11-26 16:08:21.146637-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DefaultCache - LRU cache initialized, items=1, time=27us
2022-11-26 16:08:21.208491-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] CatalogManager - Cache initialized, mutable='/Users/Wo_0NDeR/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/850AA0EB-4DCD-4F76-B066-307514C13CC3/data/Containers/Data/Application/64F0F972-D450-40C2-9F5B-0C7A121FD322/Library/Caches/v1/sBc3L41ElBGY3rJkHFA/ocm-cache/', protected='/Users/Wo_0NDeR/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/850AA0EB-4DCD-4F76-B066-307514C13CC3/data/Containers/Data/Application/64F0F972-D450-40C2-9F5B-0C7A121FD322/Library/v1/sBc3L41ElBGY3rJkHFA/ocm-map/', cache_open_result=Success
2022-11-26 16:08:21.208740-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] UpdateRepository - No common journal found
2022-11-26 16:08:21.208890-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreServer - Server initialized
2022-11-26 16:08:21.209027-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] maploader:DataStoreProviderImpl - Connectivity update: requested offline mode = 0; network unreachable =0; deduce online mode to 1
2022-11-26 16:08:21.209175-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [ERROR] CatalogLinkage - Requested catalog linkage is invalid
2022-11-26 16:08:21.209509-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] UpdateRepository - No available version in the cache, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.209681-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] UpdateRepository - No common journal found
2022-11-26 16:08:21.209826-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreServer - No available protected version for hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.210026-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreServer - Adding catalog sync, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', version=59, default_cache_expiration=none, prewarm_catalog=1
2022-11-26 16:08:21.210275-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreServer - Catalog added, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', version=59, catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.210514-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Client created, cache_size=32, this=0x7f965f850a20
2022-11-26 16:08:21.210671-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] CatalogManager - Existing catalog found, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', version=59, catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.210809-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Catalog added, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', server_handle=0, client_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.210952-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Client created, cache_size=32, this=0x7f965f84f620
2022-11-26 16:08:21.211263-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] CatalogManager - Existing catalog found, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', version=59, catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.211589-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Catalog added, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', server_handle=0, client_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.211926-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Client created, cache_size=32, this=0x7f965f871620
2022-11-26 16:08:21.212207-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] CatalogManager - Existing catalog found, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', version=59, catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.212551-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Catalog added, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', server_handle=0, client_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.212827-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Client created, cache_size=32, this=0x7f965e847620
2022-11-26 16:08:21.213027-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] CatalogManager - Existing catalog found, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', version=59, catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.213348-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Catalog added, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', server_handle=0, client_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.213667-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Client created, cache_size=32, this=0x7f965e849e20
2022-11-26 16:08:21.214001-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] CatalogManager - Existing catalog found, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', version=59, catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.214325-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Catalog added, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', server_handle=0, client_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.214697-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Client created, cache_size=32, this=0x7f965f871e20
2022-11-26 16:08:21.215042-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] CatalogManager - Existing catalog found, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', version=59, catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.215314-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Catalog added, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', server_handle=0, client_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.215660-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Client created, cache_size=32, this=0x7f965e84a620
2022-11-26 16:08:21.215958-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] CatalogManager - Existing catalog found, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', version=59, catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.216247-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Catalog added, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', server_handle=0, client_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.216514-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Client created, cache_size=32, this=0x7f9660817020
2022-11-26 16:08:21.216740-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] CatalogManager - Existing catalog found, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', version=59, catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.216968-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Catalog added, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', server_handle=0, client_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.217320-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [ERROR] CatalogLinkage - Requested catalog linkage is invalid
2022-11-26 16:08:21.217624-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Client created, cache_size=32, this=0x7f965e84c420
2022-11-26 16:08:21.218121-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] CatalogManager - Existing catalog found, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', version=59, catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.218260-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreClient - Catalog added, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', server_handle=0, client_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.218599-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding data source
2022-11-26 16:08:21.218974-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding data source
2022-11-26 16:08:21.219351-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding data source
2022-11-26 16:08:21.219824-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding data source
2022-11-26 16:08:21.220275-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Render loop thread resumed
2022-11-26 16:08:21.220600-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Render loop thread already running
2022-11-26 16:08:21.220935-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [WARN ] harp-sdk - View config is empty. No map content will be displayed until valid config is provided.
2022-11-26 16:08:21.221367-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding data source
2022-11-26 16:08:21.222043-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding data source
2022-11-26 16:08:21.222264-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding renderable
2022-11-26 16:08:21.222459-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding data source
2022-11-26 16:08:21.223835-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] Adding background facade to MapView.
2022-11-26 16:08:21.236355-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C4.1.1:3] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-11-26 16:08:21.242724-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Connection 4: received failure notification
2022-11-26 16:08:21.244738-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Connection 4: failed to connect 1:61, reason -1
2022-11-26 16:08:21.247758-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Connection 4: encountered error(1:61)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.251549-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [WARN ] geoviz-mapocm - No PDS_CAT_ID in keys
2022-11-26 16:08:21.255148-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Task <FBD7A5AB-0F18-492C-B3A3-82FD610B0068>.<4> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2022-11-26 16:08:21.257274-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Data source added
2022-11-26 16:08:21.257388-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Task <FBD7A5AB-0F18-492C-B3A3-82FD610B0068>.<4> finished with error [-1004] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001ac1110 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, expensive, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <FBD7A5AB-0F18-492C-B3A3-82FD610B0068>.<4>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <FBD7A5AB-0F18-492C-B3A3-82FD610B0068>.<4>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2022-11-26 16:08:21.263776-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] ConnectivityStatusNotifier: network is reachable
2022-11-26 16:08:21.259662-0500 HelloMap[22059:397463] [log] [ERROR] Authentication - Failed to SignInClient: ApiError(ErrorCode: 11, Message: Could not connect to the server., HTTPStatusCode: -1)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.264977-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] feature_constants - positioning needs feature ´contribute'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.265892-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [INFO ] feature_constants - consent needs feature ´certified_user_consent_management'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.267493-0500 HelloMap[22059:397463] [log] [ERROR] Authorization - Authorization fail. Failed to get token: 7
2022-11-26 16:08:21.270106-0500 HelloMap[22059:397500] [log] [ERROR] Authentication - Internet connectivity is not available
2022-11-26 16:08:21.276201-0500 HelloMap[22059:397491] [log] [ERROR] maploader::MakeTokenProvider - Failed to get the authentication token: Internet connectivity is not available, error code: 7
2022-11-26 16:08:21.277180-0500 HelloMap[22059:397502] [log] [ERROR] Authentication - Internet connectivity is not available
2022-11-26 16:08:21.278572-0500 HelloMap[22059:397491] [log] [WARN ] Configuration - Download metadata failed, error_code=11, http_status_code=-4, error='Internet connectivity is not available'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.278772-0500 HelloMap[22059:397491] [log] [WARN ] DataStoreServer - Failed to prewarm, catalog_handle=0, error=kNetworkConnectionError
2022-11-26 16:08:21.279421-0500 HelloMap[22059:397448] [log] [ERROR] MapRegionSwitcher - Rescheduling authorization request for map switch as current failed with: Authentication failed
2022-11-26 16:08:21.280046-0500 HelloMap[22059:397501] [log] [ERROR] Authentication - Internet connectivity is not available
2022-11-26 16:08:21.281119-0500 HelloMap[22059:397448] [log] [ERROR] MapRegionSwitcher - Rescheduling authorization request for map switch as current failed with: Authentication failed
2022-11-26 16:08:21.308117-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] [connection] nw_socket_handle_socket_event [C5.1.1:3] Socket SO_ERROR [61: Connection refused]
2022-11-26 16:08:21.325766-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Connection 5: received failure notification
2022-11-26 16:08:21.326007-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Connection 5: failed to connect 1:61, reason -1
2022-11-26 16:08:21.326506-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Connection 5: encountered error(1:61)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.329196-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Task <B222587C-D77C-40B5-BBD1-7F5EA0AE84DD>.<5> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2022-11-26 16:08:21.330040-0500 HelloMap[22059:397448] Task <B222587C-D77C-40B5-BBD1-7F5EA0AE84DD>.<5> finished with error [-1004] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001ac1530 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, expensive, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <B222587C-D77C-40B5-BBD1-7F5EA0AE84DD>.<5>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <B222587C-D77C-40B5-BBD1-7F5EA0AE84DD>.<5>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
2022-11-26 16:08:21.330633-0500 HelloMap[22059:397464] [log] [ERROR] Authentication - Failed to SignInClient: ApiError(ErrorCode: 11, Message: Could not connect to the server., HTTPStatusCode: -1)
2022-11-26 16:08:21.331398-0500 HelloMap[22059:397464] [log] [ERROR] Authorization - Authorization fail. Failed to get token: 7
2022-11-26 16:08:21.331885-0500 HelloMap[22059:397464] [log] [ERROR] Authorization - Authorization fail. Failed to get token: 7
2022-11-26 16:08:21.333148-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [ERROR] feature_verifier - checkFeatures: contribute, error: authorization:3
2022-11-26 16:08:21.333448-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] NetworkFactory - createNetworkProtocol: using default protocol factory
2022-11-26 16:08:21.333906-0500 HelloMap[22059:397272] [log] [ERROR] feature_verifier - checkFeatures: certified_user_consent_management, error: authorization:3
2022-11-26 16:08:21.335916-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-plugin-raster - Added RasterDataSource 'rasterterrain'.
2022-11-26 16:08:21.336158-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Data source added
2022-11-26 16:08:21.403742-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-plugin-omv - Added OmvDataSource 'tilezen_traffic_flow.line'.
2022-11-26 16:08:21.404025-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Data source added
2022-11-26 16:08:21.476366-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-plugin-omv - Added OmvDataSource 'tilezen_traffic_incident.point, tilezen_traffic_incident.line'.
2022-11-26 16:08:21.477050-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Data source added
2022-11-26 16:08:21.478140-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Data source added
2022-11-26 16:08:21.478827-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Data source added
2022-11-26 16:08:21.479619-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Skip applying configuration with empty filename.
2022-11-26 16:08:21.480459-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [WARN ] harp-sdk - Invalid render target at initialization time.
2022-11-26 16:08:21.481112-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [WARN ] harp-sdk - Invalid map configuration at initialization time.
2022-11-26 16:08:21.482280-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Renderable added
2022-11-26 16:08:21.482702-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Data source added
2022-11-26 16:08:21.788796-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] magma-scene - load scene geoviz/oslo/scenes/normal.day.scene.json: 0.302994
2022-11-26 16:08:21.797458-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Adding data source
2022-11-26 16:08:21.797779-0500 HelloMap[22059:397476] [log] [INFO ] harp-sdk - Data source added
2022-11-26 16:08:21.805064-0500 HelloMap[22059:397493] [log] [WARN ] ApiLookupClientImpl - LookupApi(query/v1) unsuccessful, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', error='Network request handler is empty.'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.805964-0500 HelloMap[22059:397497] [log] [WARN ] ApiLookupClientImpl - LookupApi(query/v1) unsuccessful, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', error='Network request handler is empty.'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.807759-0500 HelloMap[22059:397494] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreServer - All the linked tiles are already pending, linked_layer_group='traffic', catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.808435-0500 HelloMap[22059:397492] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreServer - All the linked tiles are already pending, linked_layer_group='traffic', catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.809193-0500 HelloMap[22059:397492] [log] [WARN ] ApiLookupClientImpl - LookupApi(query/v1) unsuccessful, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', error='Network request handler is empty.'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.813136-0500 HelloMap[22059:397492] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreServer - All the linked tiles are already pending, linked_layer_group='traffic', catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.815485-0500 HelloMap[22059:397492] [log] [WARN ] ApiLookupClientImpl - LookupApi(query/v1) unsuccessful, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', error='Network request handler is empty.'
2022-11-26 16:08:21.817372-0500 HelloMap[22059:397492] [log] [INFO ] DataStoreServer - All the linked tiles are already pending, linked_layer_group='traffic', catalog_handle=0
2022-11-26 16:08:21.818472-0500 HelloMap[22059:397492] [log] [WARN ] ApiLookupClientImpl - LookupApi(query/v1) unsuccessful, hrn='hrn:here:data::olp-here:ocm', error='Network request handler is empty.'
2022-11-26 16:08:25.998146-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Task <E71375B4-1284-4ECF-825A-36B9F8138DFE>.<26> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1004 [1:61])
2022-11-26 16:08:26.006347-0500 HelloMap[22059:397451] Task <E71375B4-1284-4ECF-825A-36B9F8138DFE>.<26> finished with error [-1004] Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1004 "Could not connect to the server." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, NSUnderlyingError=0x600001b670c0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1004 "(null)" UserInfo={_NSURLErrorNWPathKey=satisfied (Path is satisfied), interface: en0, expensive, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=61, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDataTask <E71375B4-1284-4ECF-825A-36B9F8138DFE>.<26>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(
    "LocalDataTask <E71375B4-1284-4ECF-825A-36B9F8138DFE>.<26>"
), NSLocalizedDescription=Could not connect to the server., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

If you have the Navigate edition, then I suggest to contact support directly.
If you do not have a license for the Navigate edition, please try the Explore edition.
If you do have rights for Navigate, please still try Explore. If Explore works, then your rights to Navigate need to be fixed (contact support or sales then).